# the date in Javascript is swapping between day and month in?

Tags: javascript

I Have date as a string `10/06/1991` when I need to convert to a date object the day and month value is swiping like this `Sun Oct 06 1991 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (GMT+03:00)`, but if I reverse my string to `1991/06/10` it's correct after converting.

[image]

is there any idea how to solve it?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this date? Show your code please.

Comment: Looks like a localization issue; in the US both of those dates would be interpreted exactly as you showed. But I wonder in what locale do people think 1991/06/10 is the same date as 10/06/1991 and not the same as 06/10/1991?

Comment: Because Americans write dates MM/DD/YYYY

Comment: Do you mean "swapping"?

Comment: I change the format by using momentJs `moment("10/06/1991", "DD/MM/YYYY").toDate()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot parse string to date using `Date` object unless it is in `ISO` form. Here later date - `1991/06/10` is in in correct order so js can make correct date object.

For your case, you can use any other library like `moment` for parse your given date `10/06/1991` by giving its format to `moment`, example is given below -

```js
console.log(moment("10/06/1991", "DD/MM/YYYY").toDate());
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```